# FreeBSD: How can I install kernel sources for 10.2-STABLE version?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

Lots of articles and posts on internet tell how to install the kernel sources for **FreeBSD x-RELEASE** versions, but none of them for **X-STABLE**.

For example, my FreeBSD version is **10.2-STABLE**.
How can I install its **kernel sources**?

Answer (score 2):

This method worked for me:

```
# pkg install devel/subversion
# svn checkout https://svn0.us-west.freebsd.org/base/stable/10 /usr/src
# cd /usr/src
# make clean
```

In order to **find** the sources for any other (i.e: future, older... etc) version, note the **path** in the URL: change `10` by `11` when published... and so on.

P.S: I don't know if the latest 'make clean' line is mandatory. I issued it, and the compilation worked.

Comment: The easiest way to find the sources is to go to https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/ with your browser and... well, browse.

And no, the "make clean" is not neccessary; freshly checked out sources are clean by definition.